# My species-by-species distance matrix of class dist is large

Tags: r

I have a table of attributes (att.csv) with 6 CATEGORICAL functional traits and 546 species. My community table (comm.csv) has presence/absence data for these 546 species across 7 plots. I calculated

```r
att.dis <- gowdis(att)
att.cal <- cailliez(att.dis, TRUE)
```

I can't obtain functional metrics like functional richness in `FD` package because the `dbFD` function runs indefinitely. My idea was to extract medoid species from the dendrogram at the clusters at 60% similarity to calculate the dist object on them, but I don't know how to proceed. Would someone be able to help me? I am a beginner in R.

Comment: Rather than tell us, please show us your small code block (with all needed libraries) that runs "indefinitely" with small sample data for a [mre]. To help, see [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451)

Comment: my only (wild) guess is to look at the "Warning" section for `?dbFD`, which is about crashes but might generally refer to computationally intensive bits of the procedure -- try following that advice?  More generally, for troubleshooting this kind of problem it is helpful to try running with a small subset of the data first, increase the size progressively, and see where you run into trouble (this is about getting `dbFD` to work, not about implementing an alternative procedure ...)

Comment: Where is the `cailliez` function defined? It's not in the `FD` package, is it `ade4`? Please be explicit about non-base packages.